# How do I designate objects as parts of different material groups and different vertex groups?

Tags: materials, vertex-groups, groups

Thank you for taking the time to look at my question.  I have a robot figure that is split up into a collection of various objects.  Some of these objects will make up separate vertex groups that will be paired with a bone, such as the head (consisting of the helmet, eyes, nose, mouth, etc.), but the author of the file split the objects up by color.  So, some head parts will be silver, as will some chest parts, while other parts of the head, arms, torso, and legs will be blue.  I'd like to group these for ease of use, but I'm not sure what the best way would be to go about doing it.

Put another way, I'd like objects A, B, C, D, and E to be colored blue, but A and D are part of the head, and should be in the vertex group "head", while objects B, C, F, H, and K are part of the legs, so they should be in the vertex group "leg".  How do I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Comment: Unless you plan on having the robot explode, I strongly recommend you join all the objects together, but after you have the materials set up. The question seems to indicate you need to know more about armatures and vertex groups in general, so I recommend docs.blender.org for the basics.